# Has anybody successfully used Prusa Slicer with the FlashForge Adventurer 3?

Tags: prusaslicer, flashforge-adventurer-3

I am trying to get rid of the FlashPrint slicer that comes with the Adventurer 3 due to its limited capabilities - to no success.

Cura works to some extent, Simplify3D lacks some bottom layer patterns that I would like to use. With my old cheap Monoprice Select Mini V2 PrusaSlicer or Slic3r were no problem. But for the replacement of the FlashPrint slicer for the Adventurer 3 I could not come to a solution. The Adventurer  3 starts heating up, and when the temperature has reached its value the print head directly marches to the home position - without any printing.

Does anybody have any clue?

My start and end g-codes in PrusaSlicer for the Adventurer 3 are

```
;Adventurer 3 start g-code
M118 X70.00 Y70.00 Z15.00 T0 ;echo message/serial print
M140 S[first_layer_bed_temperature] T0 ;bed temperature setting
M104 S[first_layer_temperature] T0 ;nozzle temperature setting
M104 S0 T1 ;no second nozzle
M107 ;disable cooling fan
G90 ;absolute positioning
G28 ;home
M132 X Y Z A B ;load current home position
G1 Z50.000 F420 ;linear move
;G161 X Y F3300 ;home axes to minimum
M7 T0 ;wait for bed
M6 T0 ;wait for nozzle
M651 ;chassis fan on
M907 X100 Y100 Z40 A100 B20
M108 T0 ;tool change
...
;Adventurer 3 end g-code
M107                   ;disable cooling fan
M104 S0 T0         ;nozzle temperature setting
M140 S0 T0 ;bed temperature setting
G162 Z F1800 ;home axes to maximum
G28 X Y ;home
M132 X Y A B ;load current home position
M652 ;chassis fan off
G91 ;relative positioning
M18 ;motor current stop
;end Adventurer 3
```

These start and end g-codes work (with minor modifications) also with Cura and are derived from analyzing the .g-files generated by FlashPrint slicer.
How can I add .g-code files of FlashPrint and PrusaSlicer here?

Comment: Going to home position may indicate that the bed is incorrectly configured in the slicer. I believe the bed is 150x150x150 mm with the origin in the center: (75, 75).

Comment: You can post a link to the G-code when you have posted it on e.g. PasteBin.com

Comment: @Perot Did you ever get this to work?  I would like to try prusa with my adventurer and curious how it worked out for you.